# Reading a iostream until a string delimiter is found

Tags: c++

I currently have a function that reads from a stream until a predefined stream-stopper is found. The only way I could currently get it up and running is by using std::getline and having one character followed by a newline (in my case `char(3)`) as my stream-stopper.

```
std::string readuntil(std::istream& in) {
    std::string text;
    std::getline(in, text, char(3));
    return text;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the same but with a larger string as my stream-stopper? I don't mind it having to be followed by a new-line, but I want my delimiter to be a random string of some size so that the probability of it occurring by change in the stream is very very low.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @ForceBru not exactly a duplicate, since I don't want to read the stream past the delimiter, so that the after-the-delimiter parts can be read at another time.

Comment: Doing this efficiently is non trivial if you can't load the whole file into memory. You can repeatedly fill a buffer and check that but you need to allow for the buffer slicing your search term in half.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that your requirements are:

- a function taking an istream ref and a string as parameter
- the string is a delimiter and the function must return a string containing all the characters that arrived before it
- the stream must be positioned immediately after the delimiter for further processing.

AFAIK, neither the C++ nor the C standard library contain a function for that. I would just:

- read until the last character of the delimiter in a temporary string
- accumulate that in a global string
- iterate the 2 above actions if the global string does not end with the delimiter
- optionaly remove the delimiter from the end of the global string
- return the global string

A possible C++ implementation is:

```
std::string readuntil(std::istream& in, std::string delimiter) {
    std::string cr;
    char delim = *(delimiter.rbegin());
    size_t sz = delimiter.size(), tot;
    do {
        std::string temp;
        std::getline(in, temp, delim);
        cr += temp + delim;
        tot = cr.size();
    } while ((tot < sz) || (cr.substr(tot - sz, sz) != delimiter));
    return cr.substr(0, tot - sz);  // or return cr; if you want to keep the delimiter
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I probably just misremembered a std function for this. Your approach works 100%