# How to use getline alternative in C++ for delimiters with more than one character?

Tags: c++, stdvector, wstring

I know I can't use `getline` when I want to delimit on more than one character, so what do I use in its place? For this code example, I want to use two pipe symbols `||` instead of one pipe symbol `|`. I need to use `vector`, not `strstr` or `strtok`. Is there another function besides `getline` that will let me delimit on multiple charcters? Here is my code for one pipe symbol:

```
wchar_t *sGroups = L"group1||group2||group3";
wstringstream wSS(sGroups);
wstring wOut;
vector<wstring> vGroup;
while (wSS.good())
    {
    //getline(wSS, wOut, L'||');  // <- this does not work with getline
    getline(wSS, wOut, L'|');
    vGroup.push_back(wOut);
    }

size_t i = 0;
wchar_t sGroup[256]{};
while (i < vGroup.size())
{
if (vGroup[i].length() > 0)
    {
    StringCchCopyW(sGroup, 256, vGroup[i].c_str());

    // do something with sGroup
    }
i++;
}
```

Answer:
For the replacement of `getline`, I modified the function referenced at [multiple character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851454/reading-a-iostream-until-a-string-delimiter-is-found) for `wchar_t`:

```
std::wstring getlinemultiple(std::wistream& in, std::wstring delimiter)
{
std::wstring cr;
wchar_t delim = *(delimiter.rbegin());
size_t sz = delimiter.size(), tot;

do 
    {
    wstring temp;
    getline(in, temp, delim);
    cr += temp + delim;
    tot = cr.size();
    }
while ((tot < sz) || (cr.substr(tot - sz, sz) != delimiter));

return cr.substr(0, tot - sz);  // or return cr; if you want to keep the delimiter
}
```

And the `getline` statement changes to:

`wOut = getlinemultiple(wSS, L"||");`

Comment: OT: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) Your `while (wSS.good())` loop is just the same.

Comment: As for your problem, one possible solution is to read a whole line, one by one, and then tokenize it yourself. For example you can use the [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function to find each `"||"` sequence, and use the position returned to create a [sub-string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). Loop until there's nothing found, and create a sub-string of the last part. Using pen and paper to design code like this is usually a good idea.

Comment: You could also look at it like a special form of CSV file, and can search for a library which can handle multi-character separators to help you.

Comment: You don't use anything "in its place". You write your own code to parse input and look for multiple delimiters. There's nothing magical about `std::getline`, it's just a dozen or so lines of C++ code that reads an istream one character at a time, until a specific char gets read, and stuffs everything into a string. You'll just do a small variation of that.

Comment: Get familiar with boost spirit. Nice library which cam make this task fast and simple.